# Too many captures in String.match Error [help]

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I get this error "too many captures" on this line:

```
gM.webServiceUserId,  mute, volume, gM.roundCount,gM.puntajeTotal,gM.tiempo,gM.facebookLogro,gM.twitterLogro,gM.a,gM.b,gM.c,gM.d,gM.e,gM.f,gM.g,gM.h,gM.i,gM.j,gM.k,gM.l,gM.m,gM.n,gM.o,gM.p,gM.q,gM.r,gM.s,gM.t,gM.u,gM.v,gM.w,gM.x,gM.y,gM.z = string.match(saveData, "(%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+) (%d+)")
```

its a total of 34 data on my file.
what I want to do here is assign each line to the variables
example:

```
on file ( 1,2,3,4,5)
var1=1
var2=2
var3= 3
var4= 4
var5 = 5
```

I got this error when I added more variables please help me find a solution

the things I wanna do here is to save 34 variables into 1 file(system.DocumentsDirectory), 
when the game shutdowns, and then load them again when the game launch...
it works but with a few variables but when I added more I get that error....

lua  code
corona sdk

Comment: Using a ["split"](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) approach would avoid this error. However, I'd look into [serialization](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) (not to mention actual objects!) to make life easier.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you could do is store your data into the file differently, using a key=value format:

```
 local saveData = ''
 for k, v in gM do
    saveData = (saveData..k..'='..v..',')
 end
 -- Your code to write the saveData into the save file
```

Afterwards, you would be able to load / retrieve from the file like that:

```
 for k, v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+)=(%d+)") do
    gM[k] = v
 end
```

Note that this would only work for the gM variables :)
You would need to store mute and volume in gM too (gM.mute, gM.volume).

Comment: +1, I'd use `'\n'` instead of `','
` when saving, and `"(%w+)%s*=%s*(%d+)"` for robustness when reading.